# abcde program in python

Tags: string, python-3.x

someone could help me with this code. 
Well I need to create a program in python  that ask the user a string and a numero and the program has to do this:

```
string=abcde
number=1
bcdea
```

Other examples  with different  Number and the same string:

```
Computing Number 2:
cdea
Computing Number 28:
deabc
```

My first try was this:

```
string=input ("Enter the string")

number=int (input ("Enter a number"))

print(string[numero:]+string[0:numero])
```

Using "abcde" as the string and 28 as the number it prints "abcde" instead of "deabc"
What do I have to do?
I know that there's something involving slicing But I don't get it.

Comment: Use modular arithmetic. Presumably your class has discussed the operator `%`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that 28 is larger than the size of the string, and when you take a slice that is larger than the string, you get the whole string again and likewise when you take a slice from a point beyond the limits of the string you get nothing.

The solution is to use the [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) operator `%` of the number over the size of the string

Answer (score 0):

```
s=input ("Enter the string")
n=int (input ("Enter a number"))

l=len(s)

print(str[n%l:]+str[:n%l])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.